# Junit Test unable to load Properties File

Tags: junit

I'm trying to run a simple test to check values in a properties file which I've saved in the src/test/resources folder of my Maven project but the JUnit test is failing. My test is picking up the File OK but it doesn't return the expected value as the file doesn't look like its getting loaded.  Anyone else have a similar issue? My code/test are as follows:

My Application Context File:

```
<bean id="myProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:test.properties"/>
</bean>
```

My Code:

```
@Resource(name = "myProps") private Properties myProps;
@Value("#{myProps['totalNumberOfChanges']}") private String totalNumberOfChangesStr;
@Value("#{myProps['delayTime']}") private String delayTimeStr;

    public void parseAttributesFromConfigFile() {
        String methodName = "parsePropertyAttributesFromConfigFile";
        try {
            totalNumberOfChanges = Integer.parseInt(totalNumberOfChangesStr);
            delayTime = Integer.parseInt(delayTimeStr);
            numEntriesToIterateThru = (totalNumberOfChanges / delayTime);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            LOGGER.error(methodName, "", "Number Format Exception Occured" + nfe.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My Junit Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/spring/Testpu.xml" })
public class ConfigPropertiesTest {
    private final int NUM_ENTRIES_TO_ITERATE_THRU = 100;
    private final int TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_CHANGES = 100000;
    private final int DELAY_TIME = 1000;

    private ConfigProperties configProperties;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        configProperties = new ConfigProperties();
    }

    @Test
    public final void testParseAttributesFromConfigFileIsCalled() {
        configProperties.parseAttributesFromConfigFile();

        int numEntriesToIterateOver = configProperties.getNumEntriesToIterateThru();
        assertEquals(numEntriesToIterateOver, NUM_ENTRIES_TO_ITERATE_THRU);

        int numberOfChanges = configProperties.getTotalNumberOfChanges();
        assertEquals(numberOfChanges, TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_CHANGES);

        int delayTime = configProperties.getDelayTime();
        assertEquals(delayTime, DELAY_TIME);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify this statement: `My test is picking up the File OK but it doesn't return the expected value as the file doesn't look like its getting loaded`. How do you know the file is being picked up OK and if it is being picked up OK then what do you mean by `doesn't look like its getting loaded`?

Comment: When i change the Filename to something invalid, i get a different error i.e. "Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test1.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist" so i'm assuming its picking up the File OK and there's a problem with the annotation or the way i've defined the Bean. Also, when i debug it the value of "totalNumberOfChangesStr" is Null so i get a Number Format Exception.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the contents of the `Properties` to try to diagnose what data you ARE getting in it? This would lead to one of two issues: 1. the data / keys are not as expected in the properties. 2. the `@Value` is not working as expected. Narrowing down the issue will help to diagnose.

Comment: I checked the keys and they look fine.  What's strange is the console is telling me the file is loaded: INFO: "Loading properties file from class path resource [test.properties]" but when i print the properties in the constructor,  it tells me its null "
myProps : null"!

Comment: It would be `null` in the constructor. It is only after the constructor has run that any of the annotations would be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the `ConfigProperties` class in your `Before` method. If you want `Spring` to populated values based on annotations the bean must be created as part of the Spring context. If you have an instance of `ConfigProperties` in your Spring context, load that instance into your test using `@Autowired`

Comment: Excellent that worked! Thanks for your help guys and your clear explanation.